# Wix: Some folders keep from previous version on upgrade

Tags: wix, upgrade, directory

We use WIX for building installation packages. There are some problems when I try install the newest version in other folder (major upgrade). In previous installation folder all subfolders are cleaned up but not removed.

1. Which unintalling algorithm is used on upgrade: from previous installer or from newest?
2. How can I remove these subfolders?

Answer (score 4):

A major upgrade first uninstalls the old version and then installs the new one. If some folders are left behind, there are two possibilities:

- They are being used by another product and cannot be uninstalled. In this case you can try creating a [verbose log](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm) to see why their components are not uninstalled.
- They were not created by the MSI install process. In this case you need an uninstall custom action which deletes them.